# CSS how to use onclick and this to bind to a different element

Tags: html, css, this

Ok, I'll try to explain as best I can.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="mobile-wrapper">
            <div id="mobile" class="mobile">
                <img src="assets/images/mobile-moments-away-img.png">
                <img id="mobile-close-btn" class="mobile-close-btn" src="assets/images/mobile-close-button-img.png" onclick="handleClose(this)">
                <img id="mobile-continue-btn" class="mobile-continue-btn" src="assets/images/mobile-continue-now-img.png">
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
const handleClose = (elem) => {
  console.log(elem);
  elem.style.display = "none";
};
```

So, currently the handclose function currently hides the element, in this case it closes the image that has `onclick="handleClose(this)`. What I need, is that when I click that image, it closes the `mobile` class instead of closing that image. So I am unsure how to reference the `mobile` class whilst still using `this`.

*I have to use `this` as I have been asked too. Because I have the same HTML as above but for different images, as the JavaScript functions will doing the same thing for the above HTML as well as the different images I have. For example: My handleclose function will be using different elements but doing the same thing, hence why I am using `this`. So I would appreciate some help with this, and not to be told to do it a different way ie `getelementbyid` as that's not what I need.*

Also, how would I be able to use `elem.parentElement` in this function, where `popUp` should be `elem.parentElement`

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  if (!cookieExists()) {
    popUp.style.visibility = "visible";
    // popUp.style.top = "10vh";
    document.cookie = `${cookieName}=true;max-age=604800;SameSite=None; Secure`;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the parent element using `.parentElement`:

```js
const handleClose = (elem) => {
  elem.parentElement.style.display = "none";
};
```

```html
<div class="mobile-wrapper">
  <div id="mobile" class="mobile">
    <img src="assets/images/mobile-moments-away-img.png">
    <img id="mobile-close-btn" class="mobile-close-btn" src="assets/images/mobile-close-button-img.png" onclick="handleClose(this)">
    <img id="mobile-continue-btn" class="mobile-continue-btn" src="assets/images/mobile-continue-now-img.png">
  </div>
  <div id="mobile" class="mobile">
    <img src="assets/images/mobile-moments-away-img.png">
    <img id="mobile-close-btn" class="mobile-close-btn" src="assets/images/mobile-close-button-img.png" onclick="handleClose(this)">
    <img id="mobile-continue-btn" class="mobile-continue-btn" src="assets/images/mobile-continue-now-img.png">
  </div>
  <div id="mobile" class="mobile">
    <img src="assets/images/mobile-moments-away-img.png">
    <img id="mobile-close-btn" class="mobile-close-btn" src="assets/images/mobile-close-button-img.png" onclick="handleClose(this)">
    <img id="mobile-continue-btn" class="mobile-continue-btn" src="assets/images/mobile-continue-now-img.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have also added a second question if anyone is able to offer advice?

Comment: The above code does exactly what you are trying to achieve. It is not specific to the images there. I will edit my snippet to include more than one parent element. Also, I don't get the last part of your question. What do you mean by "where `popUp` should be `elem.parentElement`"?

Comment: So where it says `popUp` this was just a variable assigned to `getElementById(mobile)`. If I had multiple elements that needs to reuse the `visibilitychange` function, how would I access those multiple elements to call `.style.visibility = "visible";` on?

Comment: Why is `popup` assigned to a particular element on the first hand? This should not be done. Otherwise you can't reuse that function on other elements.

Comment: @KirstyM If he helped you accept the answer and open a new thread for the second question